# Stopping a timer and restarting it from other functions

Tags: c#

I have this timer,

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new 
System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(startAutoSpec);
t.Start();
```

which is scheduled to attempt to run a function (startAutoSpec) every minute, said function then runs through various codes in attempt to find a live match of League of Legends. So as it is right now it will just keep re-running this function every minute and opening multiple windows of the game which just crashes them all.

So my question is if was possible to access this timer (which is in the Main function) from i.e. the startAutoSpec function and then stop it for the time being before restarting it in another function?

Comment: Why make a new timer all the time? Make on timer, at the top of the class, set its properties in the constructor, and then start it once. The timer will then call the startAutoSpec method once a minute. If that method launches a new exe you'll get a new exe launched every minute. If you put the timer as a global variable in the class you can access it to stop it (eg from inside the startAutoSpec method)

Comment: @CaiusJard Why keep a timer around constantly when you don't need it, and force all other code in this type to be aware of it, entirely unnecessarily?  As a rule you should always strive to ensure your variables have as small of a scope as possible.  it makes it much easier to work with any given variable as you don't need to be concerned with what all might be affecting it if it's scoped very narrowly.

Comment: Sounds like you're advocating doing away with class level variables entirely, and constantly passing them around to things that need them. If it works for you, great, but I'm not sure I'd relish taking on a project coded that way? Timers in particular should be limited instance, because they're a finite resource. To this end I'd even consider making it static. One timer can run multiple different interested event handlers if it has suitable precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the definition of the timer outside of the scope of the `Main` function:

```
System.Timers.Timer t;

void Main()
{
  t = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalMilliseconds);
  t.AutoReset = true;
  t.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(startAutoSpec);
  t.Start();
}

void SomeOtherFunction()
{
  t.Stop();
}
```

If you don't understand why this works, google "Variable Scope".

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter passed to the event handler, called the "sender", is the object that fired the event, in this case, the timer.  You can cast it to the right type and then stop it.

Answer (score -1):

Make a task which runs `startAutoSpec`.

Change the Action for `t.Elapsed` to the following:

```
t.Elapsed += () => 
    { 
        if (autoSpecTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            autoSpecTask = new Task(() => startAutoSpec);
            autoSpecTask.Start();
        }
    }
```